# Dynamic elements changes in current version of Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

I was wondering how to use a dynamic elements in Orbeon. In the sandbox of Orbeon exists an example called dynamic-dropdown (`http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xforms-sandbox/sample/dynamic-dropdown`).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
  xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
<head>
    <title>Dynamic dropdown depending on checkboxes</title>
    <xf:model>
        <xf:instance id="selected-values" xmlns="">
            <instance>
                <pets/>
                <favorite/>
            </instance>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="pets" xmlns="">
            <root>
                <item name="Cat" value="cat"/>
                <item name="Dog" value="dog"/>
                <item name="Fish" value="fish"/>
                <item name="Cobra" value="cobra"/>
            </root>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
    <style type="text/css">
        .xforms-label { display: block; font-weight: bold }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <xf:select ref="pets" appearance="full">
        <xf:label>Please list all your pets:</xf:label>
        <xf:itemset ref="instance('pets')/item">
            <xf:label ref="@name"/>
            <xf:value ref="@value"/>
        </xf:itemset>
    </xf:select>
    <br/>
    <xf:select1 ref="favorite">
        <xf:label>Select your favorite pet:</xf:label>
        <xf:itemset>
            <xf:label/>
            <xf:value/>
        </xf:itemset>
        <xf:itemset ref="instance('pets')/item[@value = xxf:split(context()/../pets)]">
            <xf:label ref="@name"/>
            <xf:value ref="@value"/>
        </xf:itemset>
    </xf:select1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested in Orbeon 4.8 and 4.9 and does nothing. By nothing, I refer that the dropdown list does not fill up with the selected elements.

I can test it also in an "open" sandbox (http://www.argonauta.org/orbeon/xforms-sandbox/sample/dynamic-dropdown) and here is working fine. But I have no idea which version is (maybe 4.3).

The question: is the example not valid in the current version of Orbeon? is it a bug? 
If the example is not valid, what modification must be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Seems that if you change line:

`<xf:itemset ref="instance('pets')/item[@value = xxf:split(context()/../pets)]">`

To

`<xf:itemset ref="instance('pets')/item[@value = xxf:split(context()/pets)]">`

The example works in version 4.9 of Orbeon.

Comment: Jorge, indeed, the expression `context()/../pets` looks correct to me. For now, I've created an issue, and we'll investigate it. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2250

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation! for now, changing the expression works as workaround for me until next Orbeon release.

Comment: Got it, and we'll follow-up here as soon as we find more about this one, whether there is a "good" reason why this is happening, or whether this is indeed a bug.

Comment: [Issue #2250](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2250) is now fixed. I can confirm that `context()/../pets` is the correct expression and you should not use `context()/pets` because that will break again once you have the fix.